# WinJS - Hide sensitive content when in background

Tags: winjs, windows-8.1-universal

I have a WinJS universal app in Windows 8.1.  For the purposes of this question, I am only concerned with the Tablet/Desktop portion of the application.

Is there a way to obscure/hide sensitive data when the application is minimized or suspended, such that when a user Alt+Tabs they do not see anything sensitive?

I have accomplished the above in iOS and Android, but Windows is proving more difficult.

Update 1:
I was able to determine when the app is hidden using MSVisibilityChange

```
document.addEventListener('msvisibilitychange', function() {
    if(document.visibilityState == 'visible') {
        console.log('app is active');
    } else {
        console.log('app is hidden');
    }
});
```

I tried showing an image to hide any sensitive data, but the Alt+Tab task switcher still shows the sensitive data, not the image intended to hide that data.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Check point event when the app is moved to the background

```
WinJS.Application.addEventListener("checkpoint", checkpoint, false);
function checkpoint() {
    // Do Magic Here
}
```

If you handled this event and placed a div on the screen that obscured the screen somehow? that might work. When the user navigated back you could hide the screen?

Comment: In my experience, the "checkpoint" event happens when the app is suspended.  However, the app does not necessarily suspend when it is no longer visible (i.e. a different window is dragged over the app).